# Solve $f - y'\frac {\partial f}{\partial y'} = C$ for $f(y,y',x)=\sqrt{\frac{y'^2+1}{y}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

This comes up in an exercise of a physics book for finding the Brachistrochrone with calculus of variation. I should get that $x=\int\sqrt{\frac{y}{2a-y}}\,dy$ for an appropriate value of the constant $C$. However, I get:

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{\frac{y'^2+1}{y}} - y'\frac{y'}{\sqrt{\frac{y'^2+1}{y}}} &= \frac {1}{2a}\qquad\text{I'm guessing that }C=\frac{1}{2a}\\
\frac{y'^2+1}{y}-2y'^2+\frac{y'^2y}{y'^2+1}&=\frac {1}{4a^2}\\
(y'^2+1)^2+(y'y)^2-2y'^2(y'^2+1) &= \frac{y(y'^2+1)}{4a^2}\\
(y'^2+1-y'^2)^2+y'^4+(y'y)^2&=\frac {y(y^2+1)}{4a^2}\\
y'^2(y'^2+y^2)&=\frac {y(y^2+1)}{4a^2}\\
z&:=y'\\
z^2+zy-\frac{y(y^2+1)}{4a^2}&=0\end{aligned}$$

So
$$z=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=-\frac y 2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2-\frac{y(y^2+1)}{a^2}}$$

And $$x=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{-\frac y 2\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2-\frac{y(y^2+1)}{a^2}}}}$$

Comment: Why is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{\frac{y'^2 + 1}{y}}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrangian for the Brachistrochrone is $$f(y,y') = \sqrt{\frac{{1+(y')^2}}{y}}$$ and thus 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = \frac{ y'}{\sqrt{ y \, \Big(1+(y')^2\Big)}}$$ and so your Hamiltonian, i.e. conserved energy function in $y, y'$ variables, is 
$$H(y,y') = f(y,y')  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} y' = C$$ which should yield the first order ordinary differential equation
$$\sqrt{\frac{{1+(y')^2}}{y}} - \frac{ (y')^2}{\sqrt{ y \, \Big(1+(y')^2\Big)}} = C$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Thanks, I had the expression for $f$ right, which is not really the Lagrangian because it is just $\frac{1}{v}\frac{ds}{dy}\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{dy}$, but made a mistake in the computation of $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ as you pointed out.

Comment: Yes, the right Lagrangian is $\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}{y}}$. I'll edit the post. So it is only your computation error that stood in your way.